# RasterLayer 16-bits into a RasterLayer 8-bits

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I have a tried to convert a RasterLayer 16-bit into a RasterLayer 8-bit in R, but I did not have success. Any ideas ?

Thanks!

Comment: Help us help you by providing a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your problem.

Comment: What did you try? You can do `writeRaster(x, filename, datatype='INT1U')`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to convert your RasterLayer from 16-bit to 8-bit you need to stretch your values into the 8-bit interval (0-255 unsigned) first. Then you can save it as an 8bit image:

```
#sample raster
library(raster)
ras16b <- raster(x=matrix(as.integer(rnorm(180*180,1000,50)),180,180))


#convert to 0-255 using the calc. function and basic raster algebra
ras8b <- calc(ras16b, fun=function(x){((x - min(x)) * 255)/(max(x)- min(x)) + 0})

#export 8b raster
writeRaster(ras8b, '/bla/bla/ras8b.tif', datatype='INT1U')
```

You can find more information on how to normalize values into the 0-255 interval [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28559/normalize-raster-values-to-0-255)

Comment: Or do `ras8b <- stretch(ras16b, '/bla/bla/ras8b.tif', datatype='INT1U')`

Comment: I didn't know that function. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

Numbers in 16-bit have 65,536 bins or 2^16, which should equal to the value range from 0 to 65,535 while numbers in 8-bit has 256 bins or 2^8, which should equal to the value range from 0 to 255.  Therefore, all you have to do is to divide ras16b by 65,535 and multiply by 255.

ras8b <- ras16b/65535*255